# Require help with javascript form validator

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

i am relatively new to javascript and have to design a form vlalidator with the following fields

```
name must start with a capital letter and must have only the characters a-z and A-Z and 

password_field => (must contain atleast two symbols from the list [ @,#,$,%,^,& ]
```

whats the best way to meet all the above conditions? should i use`regex`c or what?

Answer (score 0):

For capital letter this holds: `str[0] >= 'A' && str[0] <= 'Z'`.

Only letters: a regexp like `/^[a-z]$/i` should match.

Length: `str.length >= 10`.

Symbols: regexp like `str.replace(/[^@#$%^&]+/, "").length >= 2`.

If you want to only use regexps for the password, you could do:

```
/[@#$%^&]{2,}/.test(str) && /.{10,}/.test(str)
```

Comment: what about not more than 4 spaces?

Comment: Well, perhaps `str.replace(/[^ ]/g, '').length <= 4`, does that fit your needs?

Comment: I think I've posted both conditions, but if you really need regexp, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

regex will definitively be helpful.

here is an axample of a validator, which is easy to customize: [validator](https://github.com/Helle1/Validator/blob/master/validator.js)

it just requires some kind of translate method - or just replace the calls with your output text.

in the html you set classes for each validator-specification like capitalletter:

`<input class="capitalletter" type="text" name="somename" />`

and then implement the function capitalletter in the validator object...

JS call will be:

```
var my_validator = new validator(yourformID);
my_validator.validate()
```